# How to open a URL and save all images on the pages

Tags: php, curl

How can i, if i want to open a URL for example: http://www.google.com/information.php and then save all images that is displayed on the information.php file and also be able to only save images between the div tag "displayimg"

Would be happy if u helpt me! All i know that i can use cURL but don't know how to make it after theese requests.

Thanks!

```
function getimg($url) {         
    $headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';              
    $headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';         
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';         
    $user_agent = 'php';         
    $process = curl_init($url);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);         
    $return = curl_exec($process);         
    curl_close($process);         
    return $return;     
} 

$imgurl = 'http://www.foodtest.ru/images/big_img/sausage_3.jpg'; 
$imagename= basename($imgurl);
if(file_exists('./tmp/'.$imagename)){continue;} 
$image = getimg($imgurl); 
file_put_contents('tmp/'.$imagename,$image);
```

EDIT:

Im using this code now, but how can i store the links in a array or so to be able to download the images to my server?

```
    require_once('simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');
require_once('url_to_absolute.php');

$url = 'http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-get-meta-tags-html-file/';

$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
    echo url_to_absolute($url, $element->src), "\n";
}
```

Comment: You need a html parser, like simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net or php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like the "Simple HTML DOM Parser" library (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Your code could look something like:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$URL = "http://www.google.com/information.php";
$dumpDir = "dumpDir/";

//Get the page as a whole    
$html = file_get_html($URL);

//Find all the images located within div
foreach($html->find("div#displayimage img") as $img){
   $src = $img->src;

   //Get filename
   $filename = substr($img->src, strrpos($img->src, "/")+1);

   //Quick fix for relative file paths
   if (strtolower(substr($src, 0, 5)) != 'http:' && strtolower(substr($src, 0, 6)) != 'https:') $src = $URL.$src;

   // Save the file
   file_put_contents($dumpDir.$filename, file_get_contents($src));
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use **wget** if you want to fetch a page with all it's contents (images, js , css, etc...).

```
$your_url = "http://www.google.com/information.php";
$your_output_dir = "/whatever/dir/you/might/use/";
$you_logs = "/your/log/dir/wget.log";
$cmd = "wget -p --convert-links $your_url -P $your_output_dir -o $you_logs";
exec($cmd);
```

do check the wget man page for help, or google search for *wget examples*.

Comment: So in this example it will only save the images from the information.php page? Or does it only log image links?

Comment: it will save the page for the url and all ressources used by the page (images, css, js, etc.)

Comment: and it saves it to what you specify into $your_output_dir

Comment: did you try wget ? Did you get to a suitable solution ?